# sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * from Student_Data where =sarthaknegi94@yahoo.com;

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to call the getAllData method from a fragment. In the code below i have passed the value of email manually so it is giving me the error SQLiteException: near "=": . But also when i tried it passing through the parameter it gave me an error SQLiteException: near "@yahoo": . I dont know what i am doing wrong.

Code:  DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Students.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Student_Data";
    private static final String COL_1 = "USERNAME";
    private static final String COL_2 = "FULLNAME";
    private static final String COL_3 = "EMAIL";
    private static final String COL_4 = "PASSWORD";
    private static final String COL_5 = "COURSE";
    private static final String COL_6 = "SEMESTER";
    private static final String COL_7 = "ROLLNO";
    private static final String COL_8 = "MOBILE";
    long result;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Creating a Table
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(USERNAME TEXT PRIMARY KEY, FULLNAME TEXT, EMAIL TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT, COURSE TEXT, SEMESTER TEXT, ROLLNO TEXT, MOBILE TEXT);" );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }


    public long insertData(String Username, String FullName, String Email, String Password, String Course, String Semester, String RollNo, String Mobile){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, Username);
        contentValues.put(COL_2, FullName);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, Email);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, Password);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, Course);
        contentValues.put(COL_6, Semester);
        contentValues.put(COL_7, RollNo);
        contentValues.put(COL_8, Mobile);



        try{

            result =  db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = -1;
        }



        return result;


    }


    //To get all data
    public Cursor getAllData(String email){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where" + " =" + "sarthaknegi94@yahoo.com" + ";", null);
    }

    //When updating the data
    public boolean updateData(String Username, String FullName, String Email, String Password, String Course, String Semester, String RollNo, String Mobile){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, Username);
        contentValues.put(COL_2, FullName);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, Email);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, Password);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, Course);
        contentValues.put(COL_6, Semester);
        contentValues.put(COL_7, RollNo);
        contentValues.put(COL_8, Mobile);
       int result = db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, " Username = ?", new String[] {Username});
        if (result  > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the fragment

```
  db = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        Cursor res = db.getAllData(email);
```

Comment: use parameters...

Comment: well your query isn't valid syntax so start there.

Comment: where *something* = "sarthaknegi94@yahoo.com"

Comment: like @Selvin said: use `selectionArgs` (the second parameter) when calling  `rawQuery()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `COL_3`, I guess you are searching for the email adress.

You should use the second parameter, the selection args:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + COL_3+" =?", new String[]{"sarthaknegi94@yahoo.com"});
```

If you are using selection args, don´t forget  `?`, as stated in the API:

**You may include ?s in where clause in the query, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs. The values will be bound as Strings.**

Comment: the second solution is the preferred one, this is why the `selectionArgs` are for

Comment: yes, I aggree....for the first, I am not sure to set it in single quotation marks,,,,I´m just a little bit rusty in SQLite....

Comment: the first will make the query string like this `SELECT * from some_table where some_field = sarthaknegi94@yahoo.com);`, how is it supposed to work?